# React Functional Components - how to delete component from within?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I have an Alert component I am displaying based on user actions:

```
export default function Alert({text, type, hideable = true, stick = true}) {
    const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);
    const [id, setId] = useState(makeId(5));
    const alertEl = (
        <div key={id} id={id} className={"fade alert alert-" + type} role="alert">
            {hideable
                ? <span className="icon-close close" onClick={e => fadeOut()}> </span>
                : ''
            }
            {text}
        </div>
    );

    function fadeOut() {
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add('fade-out');
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            setHide(true);
        }, 500)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!stick) {
            window.setTimeout(() => fadeOut(), 3000);
        }
    }, [])

    if (hide) return '';
    return alertEl;
}
```

It's used like this:

```
setResponseAlert(<Alert 
    text="Please check the field errors and try again." 
    type="danger" stick={false} hideable={false}
/>)
```

The problem is that instantiating the Alert component is still returning the old component. How do I implement the removal of the Alert component once it fades away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass down the `setResponseAlert` so it can be called with `null` or `undefined` instead of using the `hide` state.

Also, rather than using `getElementById`, since this is React, you should put the fade class into state somehow:

```
export default function Alert({text, type, setResponseAlert, hideable = true, stick = true}) {
    const [className, setClassName] = useState("fade alert alert-" + type);

    function fadeOut() {
        setClassName(className + ' fade-out');
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            setResponseAlert(null);
        }, 500)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!stick) {
            window.setTimeout(fadeOut, 3000);
        }
    }, [])
    return (
        <div role="alert" className={className}>
            {hideable
                ? <span className="icon-close close" onClick={e => fadeOut()}> </span>
                : ''
            }
            {text}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Good solution, thanks. It's interesting though why react is not simply just instantiating a new component even if I give it a key.

Comment: My guess is that the vDOM cycle will take care of it by ignoring the component because the change does not actually modify the DOM.